# SQL Trim after final semi colon

Tags: sql, db2, trim

The following query produces the examples below. I want to pull only what is after the last (always the 3rd) semi colon. Each output will have different cities so I can't just trim it a certain amount of spaces as it will vary.

```
SELECT  MAX(E.EVENT_DESC) 
FROM    IASDB.EVENT E 
WHERE   SL.INVOICE_NO = E.INVOICE_NO 
AND     E.EVENT_CODE IN 'EDL'
```

Examples:

```
Consignee;Jeffersonville,IN;J 6

Consignee;Nashville,TN;J 14
```

What do I need to do to only pull the characters that come after the last semi colon? (ex: 'J 6' or 'J 14')

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Btw: the query shown will **not** generate the output shown. The query will only return a single row, never two rows.

Comment: this post shows a split type function on a character using CHARINDEX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260044/how-to-split-a-string-after-specific-character-in-sql-server-and-update-this-val

Comment: DbVisualizer is a SQL client **not** a DBMS. It's hard to believe that you don't know which DBMS you are connecting to using that tool

Comment: although i am zero in DB2 but here is link which definitely solves your purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227798/database-substring-upto-first-occurence-of-character     you need to use right function in your case because you want to get text only after last semicolon

Comment: Which DB2? locate_in_string might help you here if you have a new enough version.

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  You should be getting an error on `SL.INVOICE_NO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in DB2:

```
SELECT  MAX(RIGHT(
         E.EVENT_DESC
        ,LENGTH(E.EVENT_DESC) - LOCATE_IN_STRING(E.EVENT_DESC,';',-1)))
FROM    IASDB.EVENT E 
WHERE   SL.INVOICE_NO = E.INVOICE_NO 
AND     E.EVENT_CODE IN 'EDL'
```

Comment: I don't know which version or where to find it. This gives me [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]

Comment: Correction. It works! Just missing a parenthesis. Thank you!

Comment: I think I fixed the missing parenthesis there. You'll have to tell me because I don't have DB2 on my system these days

Comment: Is there a way to trim it after the characters I want? Let's assume I only need a fixed 4 characters. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Just  MAX(RIGHT(
         E.EVENT_DESC,4))